# Does the snap in Avengers work the same for everyone?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

In Avengers: Infinity War, we see that after Thanos snaps his fingers, he appears in a scene where he is in an orange space (the soul stone?) with a child version of Gamora.

However, in Avengers: Endgame, we see that both Hulk and Iron Man snap, and nothing extra happens.

Is there some reason that Thanos had a different experience than the other two?

Comment: For one thing, neither Bruce or Tony lost anyone to the Soul Stone...only Hawkeye did,

Comment: @Paulie_D Does this mean that the person who makes the sacrifice of the soul stone is the only one to experience that effect? If Hawkeye was the one to snap, would he see Black Widow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It is the same, we just don't see the scenes**

The directors confirmed there was a deleted scene where Tony went to the same place Thanos went when he snapped his fingers:

> The Russos, in an appearance on the HappySadConfused podcast, said that a scene showed Tony interacting with a teenage Morgan immediately after snapping his fingers, similar to how Thanos went into the metaphysical world after he’d snapped his fingers. “There was an idea that we had that Tony was going to go into the metaphysical way station that Thanos goes in when he snapped his fingers. And that there was going to be a future version of his daughter in that way station,” Joe Russo said.
>
> The idea of the scene was to give Tony a feeling of solace as he died. But a similar objective was accomplished by the scene that ended up being in the movie, when Pepper Potts tells him it’s all going to be OK. 
>   “The intention was that his future daughter--because these films are dealing with magic--forgave him and sort of gave him peace to go. And the idea felt resonant. But it was just too many ideas in an overly complicated movie,” Joe continued.
>
> [Source](https://www.hindustantimes.com/hollywood/avengers-endgame-deleted-scene-took-tony-stark-to-the-afterlife-here-s-why-it-was-cut/story-mTf9DwBTDXSUkJS0eIjnPJ.html)